# display back button in the actionbar

Tags: android, android-actionbar

There's a actionbar in my activity and I have a custom view and a back arrow in there. But some devices(samsung SM-G3588V) doesn't show the back button. 
If I add a title or icon in the actionbar, then the back button shows up. But I don't want to do that. 
Is there a way to only show the back button and my custom view in the actionbar?

here's my code:

```
bar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

Comment: You sure that all button images put in your all layout.

Answer (score 0):

You sure that all button images put in your all **drawables**.

and also if not visible the

put your images in **drawable** folder and check it may be work

Comment: of course, I put all images in my drawables. Or, no devices will display the back button.